# Angular `npm install save --bootstrap` doesn't install bootstrap module

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, node-modules, npm-install

I need to install the bootstrap module in a new Angular project.

```
npm install save --bootstrap
```

> Output is below and the bootstrap module is not installed in the node_modules.

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ save@2.4.0
updated 1 package and audited 1467 packages in 5.145s

55 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

> The previous successful installation indicated at least 10+ packages should be added. But above output indicated just 1 package updated?

Can someone help to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I install it:

```
npm install bootstrap jquery popper.js --save-dev
```

then edit angular.json

```
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

and

```
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
```

Comment: Incredible!  Again, this error is hurting me all day: ```$ ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
Unable to find compatible package.  Using 'latest'.
Package has unmet peer dependencies. Adding the package may not succeed.
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/project' ```

Comment: are you sure you cd'd to your project folder?

Comment: Yes, positive.  I also confirm the `bootstrap` module is installed and `angular.json` is updated before installing the `ng-bootstrap`.  Very odd...

Comment: so what worked? 3 comments saying it didn't work, and then check the "solution" button?

Comment: Your post works for `bootstrap` installation. If you look closer, the fatal issue is `ng-bootstrap` installation.  Please see my post:  `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62587172/angular-install-ng-bootstrap-cannot-find-module-schematics-angular-utility-pr/62601614#62601614`.           `https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/3788`.        And I appreciate your prompt response!!